# Inserir caracter por caracter do alfabeto russo em um vetor char em C++

Tags: c++, string, char

Olá eu gostaria de saber como faço para inserir caracteres (da forma manual) do alfabeto russo em um vetor char, pois eu estou tentando da forma abaixo e da problemas na imprenssão. Segue o código:

```
#include <iostream>

int main(){

    char coisa[6];

    coisa[0]='з';
    coisa[1]='е';
    coisa[2]='м';
    coisa[3]='л';
    coisa[4]='я';

    std::cout << coisa << "\n";

}
```

Comment: Tente: `setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");`

Comment: Já tentei...continua a mesma coisa. Segue o código:                                                #include <iostream>
#include <locale.h>

int main(){

    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");

    char coisa[6];

    coisa[0]='з';
    coisa[1]='е';
    coisa[2]='м';
    coisa[3]='л';
    coisa[4]='я';

    std::cout << coisa << "\n";

}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A chamada de `setlocale( LC_ALL, "" );` (com o segundo parametro em branco), faz com que o locale padrão do programa seja setado conforme as variaveis do seu ambiente.

Se você está trabalhando com o alfabeto cirilico, certamente o ambiente onde você está executando seu programa utiliza a codificação `UTF-8`.

Segue seu exemplo modificado:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <locale>

int main(){

    setlocale( LC_ALL, "" );

    wchar_t coisa[6];

    coisa[0] = L'з';
    coisa[1] = L'е';
    coisa[2] = L'м';
    coisa[3] = L'л';
    coisa[4] = L'я';
    coisa[5] = L'\0';

    std::wcout << coisa << std::endl;
}
```

A codificação `UTF-8` cobre praticamente todos os alfabetos existentes, tornando a língua um detalhe dispensável:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <locale>


int main(){

    setlocale( LC_ALL, "" );

    std::wstring ch = L"你好世界";
    std::wstring gk = L"γειά σου κόσμος";
    std::wstring jp = L"こんにちは世界";
    std::wstring ko = L"여보세요 세계";
    std::wstring pt = L"Olá mundo!";
    std::wstring ru = L"Здравствулте мир!";

    std::wcout << L"Chinês    : " << ch << std::endl;
    std::wcout << L"Grego     : " << gk << std::endl;
    std::wcout << L"Japonês   : " << jp << std::endl;
    std::wcout << L"Coreano   : " << ko << std::endl;
    std::wcout << L"Português : " << pt << std::endl;
    std::wcout << L"Russo     : " << ru << std::endl;

}
```